# Mersenne prime variation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, mersenne-numbers

Mersenne primes are primes of the form $2^p-1$ where $p$ is some prime. I am wondering if primes of the from $q^p-2$ have been studied where $q>2$ is a prime and $p$ is also a prime. Are there primes of this form? Are there many of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, $3^2-2=7$ is a prime :)

Comment: @kludg thanks :), but I guess I meant (implicitly) if there are infinitely many

Comment: @Henrik that I know, but it does not imply that this question is harder...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A014232 is worth a look. (Note, unlike Mersenne primes, $q^n-2$ can be prime without $n$ being prime. For example $3^4-2=79$.)

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A014224 is also worth a look -- it gives the exponents that make $3^n-2$ a prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly numbers of that form that are prime, some examples:

- $3^2-2 = 7$
- $3^4-2 = 79$
- $3^5-2 = 241$
- $5^2-2 = 23$
- $7^2-2 = 47$

and some numbers of that form that are not prime:

- $3^3-2 = 25 = 5\cdot 5$
- $5^3-2 = 123 = 3\cdot 41$
- $5^4-2 = 623 = 7\cdot 89$

One of the reasons the concept of Mersenne primes is so known is that it's relatively simple to test Mersenne numbers for primality (it's quite basic to show that the exponent must be prime, which is just a simple prerequisite, but one that eliminates a fair number of candidates). I haven't heard of any tests optimised for numbers of this form (and as some of the examples show, we don't have a similar simple rule for the exponents), which probably makes these numbers much less studied.

As a result of that much less is probably known, including whether there are infinitely many.

Comment: Do you also know something about primes of the form $\frac{p^t-1}{2^l}$?

Answer (score 2):

You can observe that even the case $q=3$ could be (is) hard, because $$3^p-2=(2+1)^p-2=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{p \choose k}2^{p-k}-1$$ and this expression is more complicated than that one for Mersenne primes $2^p-1$.

A short remark: If you want to generate primes of the form $6k+1$ with sequences $q^p-2$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes  then because $q^p-2=6k+1$ implies $q=3$ you can observe that the only prime number $q$ of all the primes for which the expression $q^p-2$ can give a prime of the form $6k+1$ is the prime $q=3$.

Comment: Adding to that insight, to obtain a prime of the form $6k-1$, where $q^p=6k+1$, either $p=2$ or if not (i.e. if $p$ is odd), $q$ must have the form $6m+1$

Comment: @KeithBackman Yes, although our observations are elementary, it can be concluded from them that $q^p-2$ for $(q,p) \in \mathbb P \times \mathbb P$ will generate not very much primes, in the sense of precisely defined densities.

Comment: Of course, not *only* from them, some other results are needed.

Comment: $$p\not\equiv 3\bmod 4,15\bmod 16, 7\bmod 18,17\bmod 28 $$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

we have the following:

- $q\equiv 3\bmod 5\implies p\not\equiv 3\bmod 4 \hspace{30pt}\text{$q\equiv 2\bmod 5\implies p\not\equiv 1\bmod 4$}$
- $q\equiv 2\bmod 7\implies p\not\equiv 1\bmod 3\hspace{30pt}q\equiv 4\bmod 7\implies p\not\equiv 2\bmod 3$
- $q\equiv 2\bmod 11\implies p\not\equiv 1\bmod 10\hspace{30pt}q\equiv 6\bmod 11\implies p\not\equiv 9\bmod 10$
- $q\equiv 7\bmod 11\implies p\not\equiv 3\bmod 10\hspace{30pt}q\equiv 8\bmod 11\implies p\not\equiv 7\bmod 10$
- etc.

all by figuring out orders mod primes and discrete logs of 2.

Comment: This can also show that any prime $q\equiv 2 \bmod 35$ can only have $p\equiv 11 \bmod 12$. This follows from $1,7 \bmod 12$ being eliminated via the $2 \bmod 7$ implication and $5 \bmod 12$ being eliminated by the $2 \bmod 5$ implication.